# How to set jQuery.data() using object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to use the .data() method to store data using a variable. However, for some reason it isn't working. Here is my proof of concept code:

```
var option = 'x';
$(this).data({ 'x' : 0 });
alert($(this).data(option));
$(this).data({ option : 20 });
alert($(this).data(option));
```

Surprisingly both of the alerts return 0 as opposed to 0 and then 20. Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Since this is answered, let me tell you a secret: User Chrome or Firefox developer tools and use console.log(...) instead of alert(...), it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `option` keyword in your object literal is being interpreted as a literal string for the key, rather than `x` (this is just how object literals work).  If you want to be able to use a variable key, you'll need to use a temporary object.  E.g.,

```
var option = 'x';
$(this).data({ 'x' : 0 });
alert($(this).data(option));
// create a data object so you can use a variable for the key
var obj = {};
obj[option] = 20;
$(this).data(obj);
alert($(this).data(option));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because in the second version, you are referencing the key "option" instead of the variable option (key "x").

```
var option = 'x';
$(this).data({ 'x' : 7 });
console.log($(this).data(option));
$(this).data({ option : 20 });
console.log($(this).data('option'));
```

A simpler version of this:

```
option = 'x';
console.log({option: 20});
```

Outputs:

```
Object { option=20 }
```

You can however use the [key value syntax](http://api.jquery.com/data/) with a variable.

```
$(this).data(option, 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, how can I set the data value of 'x' without explicitly using 'x'? Or how do I set the value of 'x' without using 'x'. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to access the property... like this..

```
$(this).data({ option : 20 });
alert($(this).data('option'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your second one

```
$(this).data({ option : 20 });
```

sets `20` to the `option` property, when you are actually meaning to set it to the `x` property.

I think this is what you are wanting to do instead:

```
var option = 'x'; 
$(this).data({ x : 0 }); 
alert($(this).data(option)); 
$(this).data({ x : 20 }); 
alert($(this).data(option));
```

Alternatively, you can instead use the key value syntax like this:

```
var option = 'x'; 
$(this).data(option, 0); 
alert($(this).data(option)); 
$(this).data(option, 20); 
alert($(this).data(option));
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to the data object cannot be a variable.

What you can do is:

```
var option = 'x';
var data = {};
data['x'] = '0';
$(this).data(data);
alert($(this).data(option));
```